# Save the base name of each path in a list to a new list

Tags: ansible

I have a list of paths which I want to transform to a list of file names in a new variable, i.e. from this:

```
paths:
- a/b/c/d.txt
- e/f/g/h.txt
```

To this:

```
filenames:
- d.txt
- h.txt
```

How do I make this debug print into a `set_fact` directive with a new variable?

```
- name: "Show base name, but how to save the list?"
  debug: msg={{ item | basename }}
  loop: "{{ paths }}"
```

I can use `map(regex_replace)`, but I'm looking for a less hacky way to achieve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Map* the filter [basename](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names). For example,

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        files: "{{ paths | map('basename') | list }}"
    - debug:
        var: files
```

gives

```yaml
  files:
  - d.txt
  - h.txt
```